# `conda skeleton` command produces invalid choice error

Tags: r, conda

I am using R through my anaconda installation. I want to install an R package (`MatchIt`) that is in CRAN but not in `r-essentials`. However, when I run `conda skeleton cran MatchIt` I get back the error:

```
usage: conda [-h] [-V] command ...
conda: error: argument command: invalid choice: '/Users/<user>/anaconda/bin/conda' (choose from 'info', 'help', 'list', 'search', 'create', 'install', 'update', 'upgrade', 'remove', 'uninstall', 'config', 'clean', 'package')
```

Strangely, I haven't been able to find much about this error -- I am using MAC OS, so the issue isn't Windows related.

Answer (score 3):

Since `conda skeleton` is a command that is a part of the `conda-build` package instead of built-in to the default conda, you need to run `conda install conda-build` first